Compact Riemann Surfactes with Group Structure
Let $X$ be compact Riemann surface with the structure of a complex
Lie group, ie the multipliciation map $m:G \times G \to G$ is holomorphic (+certain usual diagrams satisfy axiomatic group law diagrams).
Question: What is meant by often in literature quoted as "standard compactness argument" which shows that group law is here even commutative; eg see in part first of theses notes.

Complex compact connected Lie groups are abelian - see for example here.
